# Converting html to plain text without parsing c++?

Tags: c++, html-parsing

I want to remove all html tag from the text. 
But I don't want to parse whole document using any dom library because creating a dom tree will be overhead on the performance, as I don't care about the structure.

Is there any fast and efficient way to convert html to plain text ?

Comment: I don't know `c++`, but can you just iterate over the characters in the string, if the character is a `<` wait until you hit the `>`, otherwise append the character to some kind of string-builder?

Comment: @Scrum Meister: What about head elements or other non content tags?

Comment: What is plain text? To you simply want to strip all tags out of the document, or perform some kind of structured output (title, headers, etc)?

Comment: @Yann Ramin 
I want to strip all tags.

Comment: @fox32 Why wouldn't it work? all the OP wants is to *remove all html tag from the text*. as long as the html is valid, every `<` will have a end `>` whether there is text in between, or if the tag ends with a `/>`

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: one addition, you need to check that the closing `>` is not within string e.g. `attr="abc<>"`. A very simple state-machine parser

Comment: @ The Scrum Meister
It is not sure that html will be 100% valid every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need an in-memory DOM tree, use a parser with a SAX interface. Mind that some real-world HTML might need fault-tolerant parsing, though.

Comment: I will again having two question. 
1. Is there any good c++ SAX parser ?
2. Can you please give more information about your point " Mind that some real-world HTML might need fault-tolerant parsing, though."

Comment: @Vivek: HTML in the real-world isn't always perfect. People make little mistakes with it that browsers let you get away with. You'll have to bear this in mind when writing your parser.

Comment: @Tomalak , Jim , Itcmelo 
thanks for reply. 
I will try with : xmlsoft.org